# How can I route to a page only when a post action in the actions page is successful while doing an api post call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a form component and after filling the form and putting all data, if you press submit it goes to proectaction and does an axios api post call.
if successful I want it to go back to "/dashboard"

```
/* eslint-disable comma-dangle */
/* eslint-disable arrow-parens */
import axios from 'axios';
// import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GET_ERRORS } from './types';


const createProject = (project) => async dispatch => {
  await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/project', project)


    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: error.response.data
      });
    });
};


export default createProject;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

EDIT: make sure you are passing the history prop to the action, or make the push when you're using the action on the component.

```
const createProject = (project, history) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/project', project)
    history.push('/')       // <---- Make the push here only after post success.
  } catch(error) {
    dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: error.response.data
      });
  }
};
```

try catch block then a history push to a different route.

alternatively:

```
const createProjectHandler = async () => {
  createProject(project).then(() => {
    props.history.push('/')
  })

}
```

this only works when you're returning the axios call. I'm not sure if its the same with async and await.